# Andengine Game Jerky and laggy

Tags: multithreading, andengine, lag, scene

I have a scene of size 2000 * 2000. I have 14 players and 100 food. Food are very small say 20 * 20 and my players increase by eating the foods, foods are regenerated.
I am using  pixel perfect collision of [MakersF](https://github.com/MakersF) to detect collisions between the food and my players. But the game jerks. I have tried collisions in

1. `onManagedUpdate` of all Players. (I have exteneded `PixelPerfectSprite` for creating my `AnimatedPerfectSprite`)
2. `updateHandler` of the my`Scene`.
3. I had also tried the code in `TimerHandler`
4. Created a new `Thread` and ran the code in that `Thread`.

But In all the above 4 cases my Game becomes laggy and No 4 doesn't work properly in all the devices.

I am providing the code I have done in a Separate `Thread`

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        for(int i = 0; i < gsi.enemy.length; i ++){                               
            for(int j = 0; j < gsi.foodSprite.length; j ++){
                if(gsi.foodSprite[j].isVisible()){
                    if(gsi.playerDot.collidesWith(gsi.foodCenterRectangle[j])){
                        gsi.foodSprite[j].setVisible(false);
                        if(gsi.playerSize < gsi.imageChangeValue){
                            gsi.playerSize = gsi.playerSize + gsi.oneFoodEatIncrement;
                            if(gsi.playerSize > gsi.imageChangeValue){
                                gsi.playerSize = 1.3f;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            gsi.playerSize = gsi.playerSize + (gsi.oneFoodEatIncrement/5f);
                        }   
                    }
                }                    
            }               
        }
    }                   
}
```

Any Help and/or Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: limit your calculation to a reasonable number/sec!

Comment: @sjkm I know that everyone have to limit the calculations for faster processing, but will u please suggest what should I do to limit.

Comment: There is not much more to say, just limit it, using a Timer/Sleep or best with an Accumulator to have a fixed step simulation which is much easier to debug/reproduce etc.

Comment: I switched from Andengine to Libgdx, game is smooth now. I don't know the reason, but I just imported my same code according to libgdx and its workng fine.